# Statistics per node only visible to node author

Tags: 6, nodes

I want a simple block (or it could be attached to the content, I don't really care) displaying how many hits a node has had, visible on the node itself, and only visible to the user who created the node (and admins obviously).

Any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be somewhat easy to do using the [statistics module](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/statistics). I wouldn't recommend this, is it requires a database write on each page view, with is quite a performance hit.

A better solution would be to do some integration with GA or similar and get the data from there, but that would obviously require much more work.

Answer (score 2):

The [Google Analytics Reports](http://drupal.org/project/google_analytics_reports) modules offers blocks that will report on individual pages. Wouldn't this off-load the stat works to Google?